# Graph/Gremlinpython: Upsert 2 vertices and an edge from one to the other

Tags: graph, gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

I try to add (if they do not exist) 2 vertices and add an edge from the first to the other in a single query.
It would look like:

```
g.V().has("label1", "property1", "value1").fold().coalesce(
        __.unfold(),
        g.addV("label1").property("property1", "value1")
    ).as_("a").V().has("label2", "property2", "value2").fold().coalesce(
        __.unfold(),
        g.addV("label2").property("property2", value2)
    ).coalesce(
        __.inE("link").where(__.outV().as_("a")),
        __.addE("link").from_("a")
    ).next()
```

But as the `fold()` acts as a barrier, it delete the tag "a" I put on the first vertex.
My workaround is as follows:

```
g.V().has("label1", "property1", "value1").fold().coalesce(
        __.unfold(),
        g.addV("label1").property("property1", "value1")
    ).as_("a").V().has("label2", "property2", "value2").fold().coalesce(
        __.unfold(),
        g.addV("label2").property("property2", value2)
    ).coalesce(
        __.inE("link").where(__.outV().has("label1", "property1", value1)),
        __.addE("link").from_(__.V().has("label1", "property1", value1))
    ).next()
```

Can I do better? This is... ugly?

---

Okay, the `store`solution works :)
But I had a problem with the first part of the last coalesce.
I did this:

```
g.V().has("label1", "property1", "value1").fold().coalesce(
    __.unfold(),
    g.addV("label1").property("property1", "value1")
).as_("a").V().has("label2", "property2", "value2").fold().coalesce(
    __.unfold(),
    g.addV("label2").property("property2", value2)
).coalesce(
    __.inE("link").where(__.outV().where(within("a"))),
    __.addE("link").from_(select("a").unfold())
).next()
```

It works fine, thanks to Kelvin Lawrence :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps using `store` instead of `as` will give you what you need:

Here is a made up example using the Gremlin Console.

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('notyet').
......1>       fold().
......2>       coalesce(unfold(),addV('notyet')).
......3>       store('a').
......4>       V().
......5>       hasLabel('notyet2').
......6>       fold().
......7>       coalesce(unfold(),addV('notyet2')).
......8>       coalesce(__.in('link').where(within('a')),
                        addE('link').to(select('a').unfold())) 
==>e[61330][61329-link->61327]
```

Comment: The `store` part works but the first part of the coalesce does not. It creates duplicate edges. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: Are you able to update your question to include a few `addV` and `addE` steps that build a sample graph? That would help in giving you the best possible answer. Is it possible more than one vertex exists that meets the criteria of the coalesce step already before this query is run? Here is an example of an easy way to create a test graph: https://github.com/krlawrence/graph/blob/master/sample-code/quick-btree.groovy

Comment: I was able to find something that works in my context, thank you :D